# DFT N-point circular convolution of $\cos(2 \pi n/N)$ and $\sin(2 \pi n/N)$

Tags: dft

I am attempting to solve the below problem:

[image: Description]

I was able to calculate the N point DFT for a cosine which is similar to this (note, this is the DFT for $\cos(2\pi n k/N)$. So for this second image assume k in the image = 1 and m in the image =k).

[image: DFT of cos]

I used a similar method to find the $N$ point DFT of $\sin(2\pi n/N)$ with the below results (same notes on the variables as above):

[image: DFT of sin]

At this point I have $X_1(k)$ and $x_2(k)$, when I multiply these together I get a very ugly series that I can't solve. I think that I am missing something here, how should I solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT : $\cos(2\pi n/N) = 0.5e^{j2\pi n/N}+0.5e^{-j2\pi n/N}$. This itself is a IDFT equation, where $X_1[k] = 0.5\delta[k-1] + 0.5\delta[k+1]$.

Similarly for $\sin(2\pi n/N)$, $X_2[k] = (0.5/j)\delta[k-1]-(0.5/j)\delta[k+1]$.

So $Y[k] = (0.25/j)\delta[k-1] + (0.25/j)\delta[k+1]$, and $y[n] = (1/2) \times (0.5/j)e^{j2\pi n/N} -(1/2) \times (0.5/j)e^{-j2\pi n/N} = (1/2) \sin(2\pi n/N)$

To expand mathematically
$$
X_1[k] = \sum (0.5e^{j2\pi n/N}+0.5e^{-j2\pi n/N})e^{-j2\pi kn/N}$$ $$= \sum (0.5e^{j2\pi (1-k)n/N }) +(0.5e^{j2\pi (-1-k)n/N })$$ $$= 0.5\frac{(e^{j2\pi (1-k)N/N} - 1)}{(e^{j2\pi (1-k)/N} - 1)} + 0.5\frac{(e^{j2\pi (-1-k)N/N} - 1)}{(e^{j2\pi (-1-k)/N} - 1)}$$ $$= 0.5\frac{e^{j\pi(1-k)}\sin(\pi(1-k))}{(e^{j\pi/N(1-k)}\sin(\pi/N(1-k))} + 0.5\frac{e^{j\pi(-1-k)}\sin(\pi(-1-k))}{(e^{j\pi/N(-1-k)}\sin(\pi/N(-1-k))}
$$
You can use similar steps to compute $X_2[k]$. You need NOT proceed to multiply from here. Look at the numerator term of each fraction. $\sin(\pi(m-k))/\sin(\pi/N(m-k))$ is zero when $k \ne m$. For $k=m$, even before you reach the geometric series sum, you can see all terms in summation are 1. So $X[k] = N$ when $k=m$. So $X_1[k] = N\times 0.5\delta[k-1] + N \times 0.5\delta[k+1]$ . Though I am bit confused about the $N$ factor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However I have a question. You stated that the sin(pi (m-k) ) term is zero for all values except for m=k. For my problem, m=1. so to me, since sin(pi*(1-k)) = 0 for any integer k, I don't see how this term can equal anything but zero? Can you elaborate :)  Thank you :)

Comment: For $m=1$, $\sin(\pi (1-m)) = 0$ but denominator is also $0$. You cannot have $0/0$. That is why consider $m=1$ as special case.

Comment: Oh, ok. since 0/0 is indeterminate. So then I should apply something like L'Hospital's Rule (take the derivative of top and bottom and evaluate at k=1). When I do this for the x1[k] = [1/2] * [ [-pi/(-pi/N)]  + [-pi/(-pi/N)]  ]  = [1/2] * [N+N] = N when k=1 and 0 otherwise. That seems to match the answere that you got. I will try this with the sin(...) expression as well but I think I might be heading down the right path now. Thanks a lot for your help. )

Comment: Hi, I had a follow on question. So for X1[k]=0.5δ[k−1]+0.5δ[k+1], obviously this equation only has values at k=1 and k=-1. However, whenever we evaluate IDFT it is from k = 0 to N-1. In otherwords, we never have the value k=-1.   Respectfully, how do you justify having k=-1?

Comment: Oh that is because they are all periodic sequences but we consider only one period - either $k= 0$ to $N-1$ or $k=  -N/2$ to $N/2-1$. The period is $N$. So $k=-1$ is same as $k = -1 + N$ due to periodic extension which is $k = N-1$.